# how can i call web api Controller from ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I am a beginner of ASP MVC with web api.

By using below codes I tried to call a function which is written at the controller. For checking I used breakpoint so the control could not go to the controller so that I can not track actually what is going on.

The given code explains how to  pass username and password to the controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Login() {
var Login = {};
Login.username = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
Login.password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
$.ajax({

URL: 'api/Login/' + Login,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: JSON.stringify(Login),
success: function (data) {

alert("Saved successfully");
}
})
}
</script>
```

This is the controller which i used to pass

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost]
public void  Login(Login  login)
{
string user = login.UserName.ToString();
string password = login.Password.ToString();
}

}
```

Comment: The url should be `URL: 'api/Login` and no need to stringify the object - `data: Login,`

Comment: Stephen Muecke thanks for replay. its not working

Comment: Did you delete the `+ Login` from the url?

Comment: I tried two way
  URL: 'api/Login/' + Login,


  URL: 'api/Login'
but its not working!

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: try changing `data: JSON.stringify(Login)` to `data: $('#yourFormName').serializeArray()`

Comment: the function URL is not calling the control.. then after only the data want to be change...

Comment: Change "URL: 'api/Login/'" to "url: '/api/Login/' URL is case sensitive and putting a leading slash will root the call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically it's a case sensitivity problem on `URL` vs `url` combined with some unnecessary work. So change your script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Login() {

      var Login = {};
      Login.username = $("#txtUserName").val();
      Login.password = $("#txtPassword").val();

      $.ajax({
         url: '/api/Login/',
         method: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: Login,
         success: function (data) {
          alert("Saved successfully");
         },
        fail : function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
     })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 20px">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="well">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr class="success">
                <td colspan="2">
                    New User Registration
                </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input id="btnRegister" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Register" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="successModal"
             data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Success</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                            &times;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Registration Successful</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divError" class="alert alert-danger collapse">
            <a id="linkClose" class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
            <div id="divErrorText"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#linkClose').click(function() {
            $('#divError').hide('fade');
        });

        $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/account/register',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: $('#txtEmail').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    confirmPassword: $('#txtConfirmPassword').val()
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#successModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

let me know if this helps, I have used this in my register binding model.