# Pass Data from View to Controller - with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass some information from the View to the Controller.

Currently, I am doing something like the following:

```
var url = '@Url.Action((object)@ViewBag.CompID, "Print", "DataRecords")' + '?location=' + model.Location + '&startDate=' + model.StartDateTime + '&endDate=' + model.EndDateTime;

window.location.href = url;
```

I wanted to hide the location, startdate and end date from showing up in the browser url.

I was thinking about creating a model as shown below and sending the model to the Controller but not sure how to.

```
var model = {
               Location: $('#Location :selected').val(),
               StartDateTime: $("#StartDate").val(),
               EndDateTime: $("#EndDate").val()
            };
```

Note that in my case, I do not need to retrieve any data back as the Print method will do the printing.

I am open to accomplishing this besides using

```
    window.location.href
```

How can this be done using AJAX as I do not need to return back to the view with any data as the Print method action will print the the appropriate view.

Comment: You should use AJAX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i call web api Controller from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137486/how-can-i-call-web-api-controller-from-ajax)

Comment: You'll probably need to clarify - you're saying you don't need a `view` to return any data, but in fact you do (so the client can print "something") - wouldn't matter if it's Ajax or standard GET/POST (by definition they all send a `Request` and receive some `Response`) - your current code does the same (sends a `GET` with a querystring expecting some response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data from the front end to the back-end controller, you have two ways:

1. through a GET(passing parameters on the URL)
2. with a POST that you can do it via AJAX or simply putting your information inside a form with POST action to the method you want to hit in the controller

MVC will do the binding for you, all the information using the POST, for example, should be inside the form, then on the controller, you can create your model as the input and use the default MVC bindings.

My suggestion if you want to hide that information from the url is to do it via a  post(inside a form with a submit), but anyways if you click on the Network tab of the browser in both cases you should see the parameters you are passing to your controller.

There are other ways to achieve the same thing as the use of the TempData dictionary, which keeps information for a roundtrip operation between the controller and the view, but I don't recommend to proceed this way, every time I use that as a backdoor to patch my problems I feel guilty

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult HideQueryString()
    {
        return View("Tut143");
    }

    public ActionResult Print(string location, string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        //print here
        return RedirectToAction("HideQueryString");
    }

    public ActionResult Tut143()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut143</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theButton").click(function () {
                var model = {
                    Location: $('#Location :selected').val(),
                    StartDateTime: $("#StartDate").val(),
                    EndDateTime: $("#EndDate").val()
                };
                var url = '@Url.Action("Print", "Home")' + '?location=' + model.Location + '&startDate=' + model.StartDateTime + '&endDate=' + model.EndDateTime;
                window.location.href = url;
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="Location">
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
        </select>
        <input id="StartDate" type="text" value="default startdate value" />
        <input id="EndDate" type="text" value="default enddate value" />
        <input id="theButton" type="button" value="Go" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```